# Перевести код с php на python

Tags: python, php

Есть код на php. Помогите сделать тоже самое, только на python

```
$secretKey = "6cc765db400218ab83394f4f3c8e00866b05a0vq";
$data = [
    'shopId' => "4d499d82-2b99-4a7e-be26-5742c41e69e7", 
    'orderId' => "6555214",
];

ksort($data);

// Сама сигнатура
$signature= hash_hmac("sha256", json_encode($data), $secretKey);

$data = json_encode($data + ['signature' => $signature]);
```

Comment: Помочь, а не сделать всё за вас. Приведите python код, который у вас уже есть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652124/is-there-an-equivalent-of-phps-hash-hmac-in-python-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для преобразования потребуется три библиотеки `hashlib` для хэш-алгоритма `SHA256`, `hmac` - чтобы  пересылать сообщение с ключом и `json`, чтоб преобразовывать словари в строку.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import json

# Сигнатура получаемая из образца
data_php = {"orderId": "6555214", "shopId": "4d499d82-2b99-4a7e-be26-5742c41e69e7",
            "signature": "16f19d969d6ef8f2771430ffd9f49e989236732e3339c3b802fe3ff31e19f0ca"}

secret_key = "6cc765db400218ab83394f4f3c8e00866b05a0vq"
data = {'shopId': "4d499d82-2b99-4a7e-be26-5742c41e69e7", 'orderId': "6555214"}

# Обязательно сортируем ключи sort_keys=True, как в образце и
# убираем пробелы, которые образуются после json.dumps,
# так как их нет при преобразовании json_encode($data) в php
# {"orderId":"6555214","shopId":"4d499d82-2b99-4a7e-be26-5742c41e69e7"}
# {"orderId": "6555214", "shopId": "4d499d82-2b99-4a7e-be26-5742c41e69e7"}
# json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)

data["signature"] = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(),
                             json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':')).encode(),
                             hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
# .encode() нужен для получения байтовых строк с которыми работают хэш-функции

print(data_php["signature"])
print(data["signature"])
print(data["signature"] == data_php["signature"])

16f19d969d6ef8f2771430ffd9f49e989236732e3339c3b802fe3ff31e19f0ca
16f19d969d6ef8f2771430ffd9f49e989236732e3339c3b802fe3ff31e19f0ca
True
```

Спасибо сообществу stackoverflow и [Виктору Голованенко](https://qna.habr.com/q/1208330) ответы которых помогли при решении этой задачи.